# Convert image to text

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec, conversion

I got a scanned  image document from bank and I want to convert it to normal text document with images in Ubuntu.

Is there any tool for it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a number of [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) readers for linux that can convert from image to text. Look at the following options:

- [GOCR](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/): [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOCR)
- [Ocrad](http://www.gnu.org/software/ocrad/): [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocrad)
- [ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/): [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCRopus)
- [tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract): [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_%28software%29)

All the above, except ocropus, are present in the Ubuntu repository in a package of the same name.

Different readers support different image formats, so you may be limited in your options by the file format your document is in. Alternatively, you can use the [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) tool from ImageMagick to change the format if you wish to use a particular OCR reader.

Adapted from my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/28426/how-to-extract-text-with-ocr-from-a-pdf-on-linux/28434#28434).

Comment: Note that the wikipedia page on `tesseract` has important clues on how to preprocess the image to achieve good results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install "tesseract-ocr" on your Linux machine first.

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

You can do it manually from the command line:

```
tesseract -l eng input.jpg output
```

Alternatively, I have written PHP code to do the same, you can use it if you want.

Note: For running this code, the **exec** command should be enabled in php.ini.

```
<?php
//IMAGE TO TXT Conversion
    $input_file = $_REQUEST['input_file'];
    $out = explode(".",$input_file);
    
    $output_file = $out[0]."_".$out[1];
    $output_file_name  =    $output_file.".txt";
    
    echo "<br />----IMAGE To TXT conversion Started-----</br />";
    echo  exec('tesseract '.$input_file.' '.$output_file);
    echo "<br />----TXT conversion Done-----</br />";
    
    echo "<br /><b>Please Check----->".$output_file.".txt</b><br />";
    echo "Click <a target='_blank' href='".$output_file_name."'>Here </a>to view it<br />"; 
?>
```

Put this code in root folder and access it from browser, e.g:

```
http://yourserver.com?input_file=1.png
```

Note: The file `1.png` should be present in your current directory.

Comment: The image link is dead.