# Capture text on page with background white from photography

Tags: photos, ocr

I intend convert a photography, with txt on page with background white, to txt file. The purpose is capture all text on this images.

I google and I founded the imagemagick and this tools: [SCAN Image to TEXT](https://superuser.com/questions/46730/scan-image-to-text)

But this is it the best option? It is possible capture text on photography? 
Thanks

Comment: what you are trying to do is called OCR (optical character recognition).  There are many solutions for this. the option you listed might work for you.

Comment: @Sassafras_wot do you talk about imagemagick? This program it is not to be convert text to image?

Answer (score 1):

Another good and free solution (web service) is https://ocr.space/ - it works well with text on background, such as movie subtitles.

The best OCR is offered by Google, but this requires programming to use: https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Answer (score 0):

Will to buy a product?  I have used Omnipage and/or the Pro version for a long time and very happy with its results.

http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/omnipage/index.htm

The the higher your mega pixel rate of the digital camera the better.  If it is film photo then scan it at 600dpi.

Answer (score 0):

the top answer in your referenced link is similar to this. I suggest you use an existing black-box solution rather than trying to roll your own. unless that's your project.

one solution is TesseractOCR [multiplatform open source OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr)

another with an MSOffice dependency is [OCR with Microsoft® Office](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10130/OCR-with-Microsoft-Office)

and another [GOCR - open-source character recognition](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/)