# Is it possible to invoke Acrobat from the command line to perform OCR

Tags: macos, command-line, ocr

I currently have AppleScript which runs on a folder and is taking up my machine whilst it's working. I wish to be able to do it without UI interference.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Acrobat professional, these links may help:

1. [Scan setup & workflow](http://www.documentsnap.com/my-scansnap-setup-and-workflow-post-scan-processing/)
2. [Article about Applescript to monitor folder and do acrobat ocr](http://www.macworld.com/article/137091/2008/11/paperlessoffice.html) - has links to script downloads.

If you are willing to abandon acrobat as a solution and cobble together your own, you may find [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/50631/convert-scanned-images-pdf-file-to-searchable-pdf-file/50640) useful.

Comment: Thanks Dave.

Those are the scripts that I was referring to, when I mentioned using AppleScript.

The issue is that they all invoke Acrobat, and work by automating the visual side of it.

I don't want Acrobat to ever start - and merely be able to do 'its thing' by being invoked from CLI.

Comment: Then if you can leave applescript and acrobat behind, there are several posts closely related to this one that are about performing ocr on pdf files.  I would check them out.