# OCR Image based PDF

Tags: pdf, ocr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting text from a .PDF scanned book](https://superuser.com/questions/64124/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-scanned-book)
>   [How to do OCR on a PDF document?](https://superuser.com/questions/109628/how-to-do-ocr-on-a-pdf-document)

I've got a >200 page pdf manual that was produced by scanning hard copy.  I'd like to convert it to a searchable text format, but am not having any success finding a tool to do so.  Google's search results are highly polluted with crippleware trial software that can only do the first few pages of the file.  The only truly free application I found, [FreeOCR](http://www.paperfile.net/)'s pdf renderer fails to handle anything beyond the first few pages of the file.

Google's pdf viewer does OCR; but doesn't appear to provide any export option other than copy/paste; in addition to being very tedious, what it puts on the clipboard is only plaintext; which means I'd lose all of the line art and significant formatting due to horizontal placement.

Comment: @DanielAndersson Unfortunately, none of those were helpful.  Blowing the file apart into hundreds of image files and then gluing them back together would be a massive waste of time (1st and 3rd link).  I've already got plenty of tools that claim they'd do the job if I gave them money, but which I can't verify the claims of because the problematic parts of the file are beyond what they'd do for free (2nd link)

Comment: Then put that info in your question as well so people know what you have tried and not. People aren't at this site because they like guessing :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you upload your PDF to Google Drive (Docs) and have your upload conversion settings to convert images to text and then convert the document to a Google Doc (this can all be done at upload).  You should then be able to open the doc, click file > download as and select the format you want?

I just did this is a magazine page and it worked okay, not all of the fonts were recognised though.

Comment: The upload converter maxes out at a 2MB file size.  If I import it by emailing it to myself (what I tried originally), I don't run into the limitation; but don't get the conversion options.

Comment: How about this service?  It says it doesn't have any upload limits? http://www.newocr.com/

Comment: That service sort of works; but by trashing everything that's not an letter it breaks a moderate amount of formatting (most seriously some structural formulas for chemicals).

Comment: I used a pdf splitter to cut the file down below the upload limit; but the GoogleDoc converter didn't OCR the text at all; unlike what their PDF viewer does.