# How to extract text from an image-based pdf using Cuneiform in terminal

Tags: linux, pdf, fedora, ocr

> cuneiform -l eng -f text  -o outocr.txt  input.pdf

The above command, when run in terminal, outputs only the text of my PDF title page to the outocr.txt file. What should I do to make it recognize all the text in the 120-pages PDF? I am using Fedora Linux 25 (x86_64).

Answer (score 2):

This post provides an example script to read through many individual pages and create a multi-page PDF. Cuneiform by itself does not create multi-page documents.
[How to extract text with OCR from a PDF on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/28426/how-to-extract-text-with-ocr-from-a-pdf-on-linux)